# Probability of $A$ given $A$ intersection $B$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Two dice are rolled, and $A$ and $B$ stand for: $A=$ first of the numbers is an odd number, $B=$ the sum of the numbers is $4$.

How do I write down  this probability?

Comment: Given $A$ and $B$ have _both_ happened, what is the probability that $A$ has happened?

Comment: What do you mean by probability of $A$ given $A \cap B$ ? Really $\mathbb{P}(A | A \cap B)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: P(A|A ∩B)   <--- that's how it looks like, it's a homework and I don't know how to write and calculate that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A|A \cap B) = \frac{P(A \cap A \cap B)}{P(A \cap B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cap B)} = 1$

Comment: Quite the same I got earlier myself, I just wasn't certain of it. Thank you :)